# what evaluated in if(1&$i) in for loop

Tags: php

I'm trying to understand what is being evaluated in the if statement contained within the for loop  i.e what does '1&$i' expand to?

```
  for( $i= 0 ; $i <= 10 ; $i++ )
  {
         if(1&$i) {

          //do something
          }
  }
```

Comment: bitwise AND operator (http://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139/3933332)

Comment: thank you thats put me in the right bit of php docs.
on a similar vain where I see

$var /= 8; is that something similar?

Answer (score 1):

The if statement is basically saying "If `$i` is odd, then do something"

Comment: `1 & [anything]` will only ever be true if the last bit in `[anything]` is set. If `[anything]` is a number, then `1 & [anything]` will only ever be true if that number is odd